# How to return object that calls instead of return value of method (nil)

Tags: ruby

When I do this...

```
var = Foo.new(name: "bar").assign_attributes(name: "baz")
```

...`assigns_attributes` returns nil, which is then assigned to `var`.

How do I express what I want here, which instead is:

1. Create an instance of Foo
2. Call a method to change that instance of Foo
3. Assign the instance of Foo to `var`.

Is the solution to find another method, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method doesn't return `self`, there is no magic method of making it do so.

If you're in control of the code in question, it's your job to make these methods chainable by returning `self`. If the methods aren't chainable, you shouldn't try to chain them in this way.

You can use [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) as a general purpose solution...

```
var = Foo.new(name: "bar").tap do |foo|
  foo.assign_attributes(name: 'baz')
end
```

Or you can use parenthesis to complete the assignment before the method invocation...

```
(var = Foo.new(name: "bar")).assign_attributes(name: "baz")
```

But generally, you shouldn't. Why cram so much logic on one line? This is logically two separate statements, so represent it as *two separate statements*:

```
var = Foo.new(name: "bar")
var.assign_attributes(name: "baz")
```

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, I mentioned that. See the second sentence.

Comment: I apologize i did not see that although "control of the code" is of limited importance since he could just overwrite the method with aliasing and return self but that seems beyond the intended question +1.